# Airflow DAG runs after every few seconds, instead of configured schedule_interval

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I wrote my first DAG.
DAG:

```
import datetime as dt
from datetime import timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
import pandas as pd


def csvtojson():
    df = pd.read_csv("/home/v4g4x/D/Study/DataEngineering/PaulCrickard_Book/data.csv")
    for i, r in df.iterrows():
        print(r["name"])
    df.to_json("/home/v4g4x/D/Study/DataEngineering/PaulCrickard_Book/airflow/fromAirflow.json", orient="records")


default_args = {
    "owner": "VarunGawande",
    "start_date": dt.datetime(2021, 6, 29),
    "retries": 1,
    "retry_delay": dt.timedelta(minutes=5)
}

with DAG(dag_id="MyCsvDag", default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=timedelta(minutes=5)) as dag:
    print_starting = BashOperator(task_id="Starting", bash_command=" echo \"I am reading CSV now ....\"")
    CSVJson = PythonOperator(task_id="convertCSVToJson", python_callable=csvtojson)

    print_starting >> CSVJson
```

It's configured to start today, schedule a new job every 5 minutes, if fails, attempt a new job after 5 minutes, right?

However in the webserver UI, the moment I toggle the DAG from paused to unpaused.
It starts a new job every few seconds.

[image: Attempt1] [image: Attempt2] [image: Attempt3]

I guess it's pretty obvious that I'm new to this.
I saw a similar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59078961/airflow-dag-scheduled-twice-a-few-seconds-apart), but he solved it by changing his start date, but that didn't make any sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like a problem with the [`catchup`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/dag-run.html#catchup). You can do it setting `catchup = False` in the `DAG` definition.

Basically if you don't define `catchup` as `False` the DAG will run all the pending runs from the `start_date`.

Comment: Thanks that did it.